# What are the reference from the vedas about Yuga, Manvantara and Kalpa?

Tags: vedas, upanishads, yoga, kalpa, manvantara

There are 4 yugas and 1 yuga cycle is 43,200,000 years.

Satya Yuga equals 1,728,000 Human years
Treta Yuga equals 1,296,000 Human years
Dvapara Yuga equals 864,000 Human years
Kali Yuga equals 432,000 Human years

1000 such Mahayuga is called a day/night of Brahma or Kalpa. So 1 day of Brahma is 2000 Mahayuga.

Each 1000 Mahayuga is divided between 14 Manus. 1 Manu rules 71.42 Mahayuga. Therefore 1 Manvantara is 71(approx) Mahayuga

Therefore 1 year for Brahma is 360 Brahma Years i.e 360*2000=720000 Mahayuga.

The lifespan of Brahma is hundred years i.e 72000000 Mahayugas.

**So can you give verses from the Vedas and Upanishads that say this?**.

Comment: @Ikshvaku OK, but what about manvantara

Comment: The full fledged time classification is not found in the Vedas to my knowledge. It is elaborated and fleshed out in the smritis.